# I set the email requirement to true and unique to true but still one can make account with duplicate email in my django website

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Suppose I create an account with username="Ali" and with email="ali5242@gmail.com" and then I create account with different username but with the same email then upon sending post request to sign up the user, django with through error of:

```
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_profile.email
```

error image:[https://imgur.com/1CQeXSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHAlY.png) 
but even then it saves that user in the database with all the info that is provided
What should I do? I am new to django. I would love to get the solution and your advice on which topics should i research more.

---

I extended User model and now my models.py files look like this,

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

My forms.py file look like this,

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget= forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Email',  'required':'True', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    username = forms.CharField(widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Username', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget= forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter password', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget= forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Confirm password', 'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','password1','password2',)
```

my signup function look like this,

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()
            user.profile.email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            user.save()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/shop/index')
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, "pillow_site_html/signup.html", { 'form':form })
```

Comment: If you don't find your answer, check out "correy shaffer" on youtube, he has a playlist on django and one of the videos is on validation. Althought I can't remember the exact details on how to do it, the guy has a true tallent to explain. Godspeed.

Comment: ok i will see
Touten are a junior django dev? if yes can i contact u on insta or somewhere else for advice? I really want to talk with some junior dev because I m newbie rn.

Comment: I am not a django dev but was stuck home from the covid so I watched that playlist. Best advice, watch the playlist.

Comment: You need to put your data operations into a transaction so they will all rolled back when there's an exception. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/).